# Transfer and import .VCF Contacts

Tags: contacts, file-transfer, import

Samsung Galaxy S3 i9300, 4.1.2 Jelly Bean.
I have a Nokia phone with .vcf Files of Contacts
to be transferred to the Galaxy S3.
My contacts are more than 4000 in quantity which I want to transfer along with their pictures and each & every detail without any loss.
Any Reliable Suggestion / App that can do this?

Answer (score 7):

If I remember correctly, Android natively reads **VCF** files for import

Just put your **`.vcf`** file in any folder in the sdcard. Then open your *Contacts* app. Look for the *3 grey dots* on the upper right of the screen and press it. Select *Import* from the list. Next, select *Import from external memory*.

Wait for a while for it to finish. Close the app after importing your contacts and open it again to refresh the data. You should start seeing all of your contacts after that. Unfortunately *VCF* file can only contain information, no pictures, it is still stored on your nokia's memory

Comment: A little correction, forums: A `.vcf` file *CAN* have images within. Took me by surprise, too -- but my export had them (base64 encoded or something alike). I'm just not sure if Nokia handles it that way.

Comment: I have tried this option but this is crashing, while selecting all files. Or I have to choose some files in multiple option and work this out for hours. If any other solution is present that is perfect in transferring contacts from Nokia Phone to S3, will be good.

Comment: Izzy, then great, my old N85 exported plain vcf with no pics. @Satinder Tech, did you try [this guide](http://support.google.com/android/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1688401). There is also [this app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.globile.mycontactbackup&feature=search_result) if your default app keeps crashing.

Comment: I have a problem with it. For me, only ~450 of 650 contacts were imported, other hanged and phone became unresponsive. So I rebooted it after ~12 hours and still have no idea how to import other 200 contacts...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this app here:[ContactSync](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.vcard.android)

I'm using it to sync my vcards to my new galaxy and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

There's many cases where the native (Google or Samsung Contacts) VCF importer fails for android, because they have two bugs (one bug causes only a partial import, and one bug fails outright for older VCF formats).

I suggest this free alternative called [ContactsManager by hubin](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ihubin.contactsmanager), I found it after trying over a dozen options. It was able to import an old VCF with over 1,400 contacts in it in the first try. It is 100% free. I am in no way related to the app or the apps developer.