# How to import my Contact from google contact to Coolpad Android Phone

Tags: google-contacts, import

I'm living in China were Google Play is now not supported but I have a vpn so i can still access my accounts. I just lost my phone and I bought another android phone but it does not have Google on it. I can add my gmail and also Chrome and use them as long as I have my vpn on. I have opened my google contacts on my computer and would like to know how to import them to my phone.

Comment: What phone and version of android are you running? Some phones from China aren't built to google specs. So they aren't allowed to run Google Apps, kind of like custom roms. But I know if you install a custom recovery, You can flash Google Apps and get all of the google stuff again. Just need to flash the file like you would if you were installing a custom rom.

Answer (score 1):

If you visit https://contacts.google.com (Contacts Preview) you cannot export contacts. You need to vist the old Google Contacts website i.e. [https://www.google.com/contacts](https://www.google.com/contacts/u/0/?cplus=0#contacts) and export all your contacts to restore in your phone.

1. Visit the [old Google Contacts website](https://www.google.com/contacts/u/0/?cplus=0#contacts)
2. Click More > Export
3. select `All contacts` radio button to export all your contacts
4. Select `vCard format` to export your contact as a single `.vcf` file
5. Now move this `.vcf` file to your phone and [import the `.vcf` file to your phone using the inbuilt `Contacts` app](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/41136/transfer-and-import-vcf-contacts).